# Wordpress site not working on mobile browsers works good on desktop - too many redirects

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am having issues with my site vabbr.com. It works fine on desktop browsers, but It fails to load in mobile browsers saying

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have done the following:

1. Cleared all cookies in mobile
2. Checked the .htaccess, Apache config
3. Disabled all plugins and tested on plain site (still issue persists)
4. Added home&site in wp_config.php `define('WP_HOME','https://vabbr.com');` `define('WP_SITEURL','https://vabbr.com');`

Strange, when I try to access vabbr.com/wp-admin, it works fine as well and able to access the dashboard.

**.htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Apache Config**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName vabbr.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/health
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vabbr.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/vabbr.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: Other website (funandlearn.com.au) with similar configuration and hosted on the same server works fine.

**Follow up :**

Thanks for your time to look into the issue.  Found the issue.

The issue was with the theme used, it had mobile and desktop configs. Reset all the settings helped the issue.

Comment: What is it redirecting from ? What is it redirecting to ?

Comment: Is this the domain: https://vabbr.com? It seems to be working fine on mobile. Might have been a temporary cache issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It fits better  on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: That Apache Config is not complete. But I concur with veesar, it seems to be working fine on "mobile" for me as well. (?)

Answer (score 0):

If you use cloudflare, try to "Clear Cache" and "Pause". You can find it on your cloudflare overview dashboard.

If you use caching plugin on your wordpress, try to "Clear Cache" on your plugin. Make sure it's clean "ALL" your caching files. Better to disable the plugin if Clear Cache doesn't works.

If none above works. Try to reinstall the wordpress. Maybe it causes by database files.

Comment: I am not using any CDN / Cache plugin and also did a fresh reinstall of wordpress. Thanks for your thoughts.